# Windows Phone 8.1 Media Capture Rotated Incorrectly

Tags: camera, windows-phone-8.1

I'm having great difficulty getting my captured image to be rotated correctly, the bitmapencoder class doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
    private async Task CapturePhoto()
    {
        ImageEncodingProperties pIEPEncoder = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream pIMSCapture = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        using (pIMSCapture)
        {
            await cMCeCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(pIEPEncoder, pIMSCapture);

            pIMSCapture.Seek(0);

            BitmapDecoder pBDrDecoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(pIMSCapture);
            BitmapEncoder pBErEncoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(pIMSCapture, pBDrDecoder);
            pBErEncoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Fant;
            pBErEncoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = ConvertDegreesToBitmapRotation(cIntRotationDegrees);
            await pBErEncoder.FlushAsync();

            BitmapImage pBIeCapture = new BitmapImage();
            pIMSCapture.Seek(0);
            await pBIeCapture.SetSourceAsync(pIMSCapture);

            CaptureImage.Source = pBIeCapture;
            CaptureImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
            CaptureImage.Width = LayoutRoot.ActualWidth;
            CaptureImage.Height = LayoutRoot.ActualHeight;
        }

        await CleanupCameraAsync();
    }
```

Any ideas how to fix this?  The camera API seems to be my nemesis as of late, so frustrating to get anything working how I would like.

Comment: Just FYI, I can set the pBErEncoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation value to anything, it always looks the same.  Rotated clockwise by 90 degrees.

Comment: Okay I have more to add to this now,  both rotate and flip seem to work entirely different from each other on Windows 8.1 desktop.If I seek the stream to 0 prior to transcoding, rotate will NOT work, and flip will corrupt the image.

If I don't seek to 0 prior to transcoding, rotate will work, but flip produces a "component not found" exception.  I will make a small project that demonstrates this issue.  At current it seems that it is not possible for me to flip the image using the bitmap encoder on a surface pro 3 running windows 8.1, it either corrupts or throws an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an alternative solution and that's to use the WritableBitmapEx class obtained from here,

https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

This actually does what it's supposed to do, unlike the BitmapEncoder class for some reason.  Plus it's super easy to use.  Although flipping Horizontal seems to flip Vertical instead, not entirely sure why but it works anyway.  I just switched Horizontal and Vertical over.

```
    private async Task CapturePhoto()
    {
        ImageEncodingProperties pIEPEncoder = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream pIMSCapture = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        using (pIMSCapture)
        {
            await cMCeCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(pIEPEncoder, pIMSCapture);

            if(!cBlnExternalCamera)
            {
                pIMSCapture.Seek(0);
                BitmapImage pBIeCapture = new BitmapImage();
                await pBIeCapture.SetSourceAsync(pIMSCapture);

                pIMSCapture.Seek(0);
                WriteableBitmap pWBpBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(pBIeCapture.PixelWidth, pBIeCapture.PixelHeight);
                await pWBpBitmap.SetSourceAsync(pIMSCapture);

                if (cIntRotationDegrees != 0)
                    pWBpBitmap = pWBpBitmap.Rotate(cIntRotationDegrees);

                if (cBlnMirroringPreview)
                    pWBpBitmap = pWBpBitmap.Flip(cDInDisplayInformation.CurrentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.Landscape || cDInDisplayInformation.CurrentOrientation == DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped ? WriteableBitmapExtensions.FlipMode.Vertical : WriteableBitmapExtensions.FlipMode.Horizontal);

                CaptureImage.Source = pWBpBitmap;
                CaptureImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
                CaptureImage.Width = LayoutRoot.ActualWidth;
                CaptureImage.Height = LayoutRoot.ActualHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                pIMSCapture.Seek(0);
                BitmapImage pBIeCapture = new BitmapImage();
                await pBIeCapture.SetSourceAsync(pIMSCapture);

                CaptureImage.Source = pBIeCapture;
                CaptureImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
                CaptureImage.Width = LayoutRoot.ActualWidth;
                CaptureImage.Height = LayoutRoot.ActualHeight;
            }
        }

        await CleanupCameraAsync();
    }
```